# Using a class to set up a view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing an android application where the user can add and remove fields interactively. Each field the user add has some buttons, and value which the user should be able to interact with. I thought to create a subclass to handle the field I can add which will hold it's own onClickListener but I'm not sure how to do so.

Here is some pseudo code which should make my intention clear.

Say I have a class , vClass:

```
    public class sClass extends View implements onClickListener{
   this.setContextView(R.layout.vClass);//how do I do this in a correct way?
       @Override 
       public void onClick(View v){ //add code here
       }
    }
```

and aClass which is the main class of the application.

```
public class aClass extends Activity implements onClickListener{
   Button b;
   LayoutInflater i;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      this.b =(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
      b.setOnClickLister(this);

   }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
      //this is what I have now to add View
      final LinearLayout canvas =(LinearLayout)aClass.this.findViewById(R.id.main);
      View cv =this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter, canvas, false);
      canvas.addView(cv);
   }
}
```

how can I use the vClass to add elements to the aClass.

Typing this is I thought about another solution.

If I keep track of the id's of all the views I have added (without the subcomponents) can I do something of that kind:

```
View vv = findViewById(id);
Button bb = vv.findViewByIf(R.id.xmlId);
```

where id is an id I have assigned to the view which I know and xmlId is a string I have specified in the xml file?

Thanks

Yotam

For solution, read the discussion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs used in layouts are not necessarily unique, so i guess you should keep the added `Views` in an `ArrayList`, as

```
View cv =this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter, canvas, false);
this.viewList.add(cv);
canvas.addView(cv);
```

or you could declare an index member inside your `sClass` implementation, and store the added indices in an `ArrayList`:

```
private int index;

public sClass(final int index) 
{
    this.index = index;
}

public int getIndex()
{
    return this.index;
}

@override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    return ((obj instanceof sClass) && (((sClass)obj).getIndex() == this.index));
}
```

Both ways you have access to the view you want.

The button that lays inside the view is accessible via the `findViewById()` method

```
Button bb = vv.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
```

where R.id.buttonId was declared in the vv view's layout xml file, as follows:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonId" [...] />
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around and tell you how it went.

Comment: Thinking about this, I have a new question. In each View I'll place, there will be fields which should respond to onClick. I should set their onClickLister to my click listener but how can I check which was clicked? I can't use the getId() method since the id's are overloaded... Thanks

Comment: That's why you should keep tracking the `View`'s index, so when a click event is fired, you'll know exactly which view's button was clicked. Nonetheless, in the overriden `onClick(View v)` method the `view` parameter is the `Button` instance that was clicked.

Comment: If deciding to go with the custom View extension, you could insert more members inside, to perform more customized actions.

Comment: What I still don't get is how do I tell which View's button Is pressed. The only solution I see is to keep track of each id I assign (that is, assigning new ID to each object I add to the view).

Comment: No need to assign id, it's enough if you keep track of the indices, and based on them you access the proper view.

Comment: I did it in another way. (I got a rough test so I'm not completely sure). Whenever I create a field, I create a new custom view object I wrote down (sClass) which I assign all the gui element to (Button, TextView etc.) which Each has it's own onClick Listener.